# Lingual Trinity

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, language

Mr. E. L., Mr. E. E., and Mr. R. K. met together.

Mr. E. L. shows a word, 6 letters, all capital.

- In Mr. E. E.'s vision, the word means "wine."
- In Mr. R. K.'s vision, the word means "soy."

Mr. E. E. shows a word, 5 letters, all capital.

- In Mr. E. L.'s vision, the word means "bay."
- In Mr. R. K.'s vision, the word means "wow."

Mr. R. K. shows a word, 3 letters, all capital.

- In Mr. E. L.'s vision, the word means "to."
- In Mr. E. E.'s vision, the word means "it."

What are the words?

Subtle Hint:

> They are visually impaired.

Moderate Hint:

> The word Mr. E. L. presented is a mathematical term.
>  The word Mr. E. E. presented is an adjective.
>  The word Mr. R. K. presented is a pronoun.

Decisive Hint:

> Lookalike letters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while, so I'll just reveal the answer.

Mr. E. L., Mr. E. E., and Mr. R. K. stand for, as @Deusovi noticed correctly:

> **English Latin**, **Greek Greek**(**Ελληνικά Ελληνικό**), and **Russian Cyrillic**(**Русский Кириллица**), respectively.

The gimmick of the riddle is that each participant cannot

> see any letters doesn't look like a letter in his language.

The word that Mr. E. L. showed was:

> **COSINE**. Mr. E. E. saw **ΟΙΝΕ**, which means "wine", and Mr. R. K. saw **СОЕ**, which means "soy".

The word that Mr. E. E. showed was:

> **ΒΑΘΥΣ**, which means "deep". Mr. E. L. saw **BAY**, and Mr. R. K. saw **ВАУ**, which means "wow". The **У** looks slightly different from **Y**, but it's just a typeface issue, so never mind.

The word that Mr. R. K. showed was:

> **ТОЙ**, which means "that" or "those". Mr. E. L. saw **TO**, and Mr. E. E. saw **ΤΟ**, which means "it".

I really should've sought for better words, but that's it anyway.

Answer (score 6):

### Partial answer - don't have first word

The three participants are

> the English Language (E. L.) , Greek (E.E.), and Russian (R.K.) .

The words are

> ???:
>  **BAY**: `bay` = "bay"; `вау` = "wow".
>  **TO**: `to` = "to"; `το` = "it".

Comment: I don't like posting partials, especially this close and for puzzles this small. But I've tried every possible translation of "wine" into Greek that I can find, and all of them either have a non-Russian letter in all-caps, or don't mean anything when interpreted as Russian.

Comment: remember that the first word also has to look like a capital rot13(ratyvfu jbeq)

Comment: @Forgotten_User Not necessarily. The second one doesn't seem to work the other way.

Comment: On the second thought, I think there isn't too much of ambiguity. So please keep going.

Comment: If they can count correctly the number of letters maybe the word that E.E thinks is "it" is "του" in greek.

Comment: For example if you want to start a sentence with "it's his" in greek you say "είναι δικό του"."it" and "του" having the same meaning.

Comment: I have read the puzzle again.Maybe everyone shows the word to the other two in his own language.

Comment: @Dannyu NDos are they able to tell the right number of letters?

Comment: @Craftsman For every word, only its presenter knows the right number of letters.